# Its possible to make this on bootstrap 4 grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to do that on a Bootstrap grid,
can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Can you show some code that you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please **[read how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and 
[what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). 
It's expected that you **make an effort to solve the problem before asking**.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

like this!

```
<div class="container-fluid m-0 p-0">
  <div class="row justify-content-left m-0 p-0">
    <div class='col-6 m-0 p-0'>

      <div class="col-md-12 bg-primary">
        All screens
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12 d-none d-md-block bg-warning">
        B Large screen
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-6 d-md-none bg-danger">
      C small screen
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 float-left d-md-none bg-warning">
      B Small screen
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 d-none d-md-inline-block bg-danger">
      C large screen
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chulps/6hrxwvwb/)

Comment: Thank you,
from here I can do what I want

Comment: can a brother get an upvote? lol